# Object Access in chrome develeper tools doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Whenever that i tryed to access an object in chrome developer tools i see the error bellow:
VM4939:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
    at :1:13

My code is:

```
<head>
  <script> 
    var new_2ELayout;
    function doOnLoad() {
      var new_1CLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject({
        parent: document.body,
        pattern: "1C"
      });
      var new_1CLayoutA = new_1CLayout.cells("a");
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: That code is not syntactically correct; you're missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: Looks like you are just missing the closing curly brace for your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have in my opinion 2 ways to do that:

1 -  To Declare the variables outside function 
        `var new_2ELayout, new_1CLayout;`

2 - To Declare global variables

But the best of all options is the first one.

Comment: Not that I am jealous, but why has this been chosen as the accepted answer instead of mine? I say the same thing and I provide a working code sample with corrections.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `new_1CLayout` is defined inside the `doOnLoad()` function, so i't not accessible from the outside. Declare it outside.

```
var new_2ELayout, new_1CLayout;

function doOnLoad() {
      new_1CLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject({
           parent: document.body,
           pattern: "1C"
      });

      var new_1CLayoutA = new_1CLayout.cells("a");

} // and don't forget to close the function here

// Now you can log new_1CLayout outside the function
```